# What is the best way to run python scripts once per month in AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I need to run a python script file on the 20th of every month. This code will read the tsv file (stored somewhere) then call to the fee registration API and log the response to a file and save it. The processed tsv file will be moved to the processed folder.
I dont know the best way to implement this in AWS?

Manual approach is:

- Create EC2 instance, run python script
- Store tsv file on s3 (I dont know the best way to handle file upload problem)
- Use lambda to trigger on the 20th of every month.

What is the best way to implement this in AWS?
What is the best way to implement file storage and upload?

Comment: lambda for processing, cloudwatch event as trigger, s3 as storage.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without an Amazon EC2 instance:

- Create an **AWS Lambda function** that will perform the process (call API and log the response)
- Store any persistent data in an **Amazon S3 bucket** and have the Lambda function download/upload from there
- Create a **CloudWatch Events rule** to trigger the AWS Lambda function at the desired interval

AWS Lambda functions provide 512MB of storage in the `/tmp/` directory, so you can download the TSV file to there, perform your operations and then upload the resulting file back to  S3.

You will only be charged for the duration that the Lambda function actually runs.

Comment: Thank @John. I was told that the AWS Lambda limit page states the function timeout is 900 seconds (15 minutes). So in case on the 20th of the month I have a lot of tsv files/records to process and the time can be more than 15 minutes, is that ok?

Comment: Is there a way to automate file uploads from local to S3?

Comment: @H.Dang Not John but unfortunately, no - 15 minutes is hard limit. I would split the files between multiple Lambda instances and that way you can get it under 15 minutes. Try and see how many files you can process in under 15 minutes and then batch it up. Since this is a one-off, you should be fine - if it starts to go beyond one hour of processing, I'd go with an EC2 spot instance.

Comment: @H.Dang If you have so many files to process, why are you waiting until the 20th of the month to process them? Can you process them as they arrive, rather than waiting until the 20th? Worst case, you can use the Lambda function to Start an Amazon EC2 instance that can then do the processing. See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)